# Como definir o SET CLIENT_ENCODING = UTF8 de forma permanente?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou usando o PostgreSQL no meu DATABASE
As informações com acento estão sendo gravadas com problemas no acento.

**Ex:**

**ã grava como Ã£**

**Tubarão grava como TubarÃ£o**

A codificação do meu DATABASE e do meu servidor estão utilizando o *UTF8* como **ENCODING**. Só que o PostgreSQL possui uma variável de ambiente chamada **CLIENT_ENCODING** que é responsável por controlar a codificação utilizada pelo cliente que está conectado ao servidor de banco de dados.

Quando eu mando o comando **SHOW**

**SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING;**

Aparece que meu **ENCODING** é o *UNICODE*

Então, toda vez, eu tenho que usar o comando **SET**, em cada janela de query tool, para poder alterar seu valor e corrigir os acentos. Por exemplo:

**SET CLIENT_ENCODING = 'LATIN1';**

OBS.: se eu coloco *‘UTF8’*, ele não reconhece os caracteres especiais. Não sei o porquê disso, já que meu banco está em *‘UTF8’*. Ele deveria reconhecer e mostrar os acentos, quando eu coloco em set *UTF8*.

**A MINHA PERGUNTA É:**

Por favor, como posso deixar o meu cliente encoding de acordo com o banco (*UTF8*), para que não aconteça esses erros com o acento?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar o comando `SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';` ao arquivo `~/.psqlrc` (ou `%APPDATA%\postgresql\psqlrc.conf` no Windows)

Para mais detalhes, veja o **manual**: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#AEN88713

**Resposta similhar em inglês:**

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71597/postgresql-set-default-psql-client-encoding

Answer (score 0):

Você pode setar variáveis de ambiente diretamente na `ROLE` responsável pela sessão/conexão, por exemplo:

```
ALTER ROLE foobar SET CLIENT_ENCODING = 'UTF8';
```