# Criar um arquivo .bat para excluir informações de uma determinada tabela em postgresql

Tags: postgresql, delete, bat

Estou tentando executar um delete no postgre via arquivo bat, preciso que seja assim devido a uma particularidade do sistema que estou ajustando.
Entretanto, executo o arquivo e ele não exclui, tentei incluindo um commit mesmo assim não deu certo. O .bat está da seguinte forma:

```
@echo off
set PGPASSWORD=#abc123#
cd "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin"
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d BANCO_TESTE -c "delete from wfiscal.wfiscal where section = 'Impressão de DARF';"
```

Comment: Você tem uma tabela wfiscal dentro de um schema wfiscal?

Comment: Remova o `@echo off` para verificar o erro que ocorre ao executar a query, após constatar o erro e fazer a correção coloque o `@echo off` de volta..

Comment: Sim, um esquema wfiscal e a tabela wfiscal dentro desse esquema.

Comment: @Danizavtz eu fiz o teste que falou, não acusa erro, ele apenas informa DELETE 0

Comment: Pessoal, encontrei o problema, na coluna a informação tem um acento em impressão, ao executar o bate ele não reconhece o caracter especial, ficando diferente, fiz o teste alterando e removendo o acento e deu certo

Comment: Poderia verificar novamente se o elemento foi deletado na primeira execução? Outra coisa é que você passa o parâmetro -d BANCO_TESTE. Unica conclusão que eu posso chegar é que pode ser um problema de encoding, por causa do acento `ã` e pelo fato de ser windows. Poderia fazer um teste com uma string que não possui acentuação?

Comment: @Danizavtz é esse mesmo o problema, testei minutos antes da sua resposta, se eu coloco uma string sem acentuação ele deleta, pensei em usar um like pra deleter, mas ai ele não reconhece o % também pelo que vi, vou ter que conseguir uma forma de roda rum update antes do delete pra remover esse acento

Comment: Verifica se setando o encoding do client resolve, encontrei essa resposta que pode ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321194/como-definir-o-set-client-encoding-utf8-de-forma-permanente, outra alternativa é tentar remover por um atributo `integer`)

Comment: Eu pensei em roda rum update tirando o acento, entretando como consigo filtrar por outra coluna, eu montei outro filtro no delete excluindo as linhas com base em uma coluna que não tem acento, ai deu certo, de qualquer forma muito obrigado pelas dicas!