# Problema com Query C#/Postgres

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

tenho o seguinte método:

```
 private static List<ProdutosTmpModel> GetInListaPromo_caddespd(Dados dados, Empresa emp)
    {
        //busca todas os produtos das listas vigentes
        StringBuilder command1 = new StringBuilder();

        command1.Append(" SELECT  a.cod_filial, " +
                                  " a.cod_reduzido," +
                                   " a.prc_desconto," +
                                   " b.vlr_custo," +
                                   " b.prc_lucro, " +
                                   " b.vlr_venda," +
                                   " a.vlr_promocao," +
                                   " b.cod_barra," +
                                   " a.dat_fim" +
                      " FROM produto1 AS a" +
                      " INNER JOIN produto2 as b  on a.cod_reduzido = b.cod_reduzido" +
                        " WHERE a.cod_filial = " + emp.filial +
                      " AND a.dat_fim >= NOW()" +
                      " ORDER BY a.dat_fim; ");

        _GetInListaPromo = command1.ToString();

        NpgsqlConnection conn = ConectionTrier.npgSqlConection(dados.host, "5432", dados.banco, dados.usuario, dados.senha);

        conn.Open();

        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(command1.ToString(), conn);
        NpgsqlDataReader reader;
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
```

quando executo esse metodo no pc do cliente, onde esta ">" é colocado "\u003e" causando um erro de sql, porem no meu pc nao acontece isso, como posso resolver isso ?

na imagem abaixo é possivel ver o comando executado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: seu ENCODING está errado... tente definir o encoding do banco para UTF8

Comment: nao tenho autonomia para alterações no banco, sabe me dizer se teria alguma forma de "forçar" o ">" ? via código

Comment: Substitua as imagens por texto, caso contrário qualquer pessoa que tente reproduzir o problema terá de digitar TD.

Comment: qual o erro que esta ocasionando? e transformar em JSON não quer dizer que está indo errado.

Comment: Virgilio, dá erro de sintaxe, pois na hora de executar o caractere ">" é substituido por "\u003e"

Comment: Cara, dá uma olhadinha: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321194/como-definir-o-set-client-encoding-utf8-de-forma-permanente Espero que ajude

Answer (score -3):

Tenta por o seguinte na connection string:

```
Encoding=UNICODE
```

Vi [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31611255/10991202).