# Erro de encoding na hora de rodar script

Tags: sql, postgresql

bom, estou tentando rodar o script da seguinte forma:

```
psql -U [usuario] -d [banco] -f [script]
```

e no cmd aparece assim:

```
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE
COMMENT
COMMENT
psql:pais.sql:282: ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0x81 in encoding "WIN1252" has no equivalent in encoding "UTF8"
```

na minha pesquisa sobre o que esse erro pode ser, achei esses comandos:

```
SET client_encoding TO 'UTF8';
```

só que esse comando é rodando quando ja estou dentro do psql, e ele funciona. mas para rodar o script (até onde vai meu conhecimento e pelo o que as minhas pesquisas mostraram) eu só consigo rodar ele fora do psql. e fora do psql da o mesmo erro de encoding.

tem alguma alteração que posso fazer no meu arquivo sql para ele rodar como preciso?

Comment: Veja se essa resposta ajuda a resolver: [como-definir-o-set-client-encoding-utf8-de-forma-permanente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321194/como-definir-o-set-client-encoding-utf8-de-forma-permanente)